# How to fix moviepy problem no object atribute 'audio'?

Tags: python-3.11

The provided code is a Python script that creates a video from a combination of music, voice, and images. The script uses the moviepy library to manipulate the multimedia files.

The first step is to define the folders containing the music, voice, and image files, as well as the input text file and the output video file. These values are stored in variables for easy modification.

Next, the script gets a list of all the music files in the music folder and all the voice files in the voice folder using the os module. It also reads the input text file and stores the text rows in a list using the csv module. Finally, it gets a list of all the image files in the image folder.

For each iteration of the loop, the script chooses a random music file and creates an audio clip from it using AudioFileClip. It then removes the audio from the music clip using the audio attribute.

The script then iterates over the voice files, image files, and text rows simultaneously using zip. For each iteration, it creates an audio clip from the voice file, creates an image clip from the image file using ImageClip, and adds the text to the image using TextClip. These clips are then combined using CompositeVideoClip and the music clip is added to the result using CompositeAudioClip. The final clip is then added to the final_clips list.

Finally, all the clips in the final_clips list are concatenated using concatenate_videoclips and the resulting clip is written to the output file using write_videofile.

Overall, the script provides a straightforward way to create a video from a combination of multimedia files. However, there are some potential limitations and tradeoffs to consider:

The script assumes that there is an equal number of voice files, image files, and text rows. If this is not the case, the script may encounter errors or produce unexpected results.
The script chooses a random music file for each iteration, which may result in inconsistent audio throughout the video. Alternatively, the script could use a single music file or a pre-defined playlist to ensure consistency.
The script applies a fixed volume reduction to the music clip using volumex. Depending on the source audio files, this may not be sufficient to balance the audio levels. The script could use a more advanced audio processing library to normalize the audio levels.
The script uses the csv module to read the input text file, which assumes that the file is in CSV format. If the file is in a different format or contains non-standard characters, the script may encounter errors or produce unexpected results. The script could use a more robust text processing library to handle a wider range of input formats.

```
import os
import random
import csv
from moviepy.editor import *

# Define the folders containing the music, voice, and image files
music_folder, voice_folder, image_folder = (
    "nocop_music",
    "text_to_speech",
    "random_nocop_photos",
)

# Define the input text file and the output video file
text_file, output_file = "ciekawostki.csv", "output.mp4"

# Get a list of all the music files in the music folder
music_files = os.listdir(music_folder)

# Get a list of all the voice files in the voice folder
voice_files = os.listdir(voice_folder)

# Read the input text file and store the text rows in a list
texts = []
for row in csv.reader(open(text_file)):
    texts.append(row)

# Get a list of all the image files in the image folder
image_files = os.listdir(image_folder)

# Choose a random music file and create an audio clip from it
music_clip = AudioFileClip(
    os.path.join(music_folder, random.choice(music_files))
).volumex(0.1)

# Remove the audio from the music clip
music_clip.audio = None

# Create a list to store the final video clips
final_clips = []

# Iterate over the voice files, image files, and text rows simultaneously
for voice_file, image_file, text in zip(voice_files, image_files, texts):
    # Get the full path to the current voice file
    voice_path = os.path.join(voice_folder, voice_file)
    # Create an audio clip from the voice file
    voice_clip = AudioFileClip(voice_path)

    # Get the full path to the current image file
    image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, image_file)
    # Create an image clip from the image file
    image_clip = (
        ImageClip(image_path)
        # Set the duration of the image clip to match the duration of the voice clip
        .set_duration(voice_clip.duration)
        # Set the position of the image clip to the center of the screen
        .set_position(("center", "center"), relative=True)
    )

    # Create a text clip from the current text row
    text_clip = TextClip(
        text[0], fontsize=70, color="white", size=(1080, 1920)
    ).set_position(("center", "center"), relative=True)

    # Combine the image, text, and voice clips into a single video clip
    video_clip = CompositeVideoClip(
        [image_clip, text_clip.set_start(0.5), voice_clip.set_start(0.5)]
    ).set_audio(music_clip)

    # Add the video clip to the list of final clips
    final_clips.append(video_clip)

# Concatenate all the final clips into a single video clip
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(final_clips)

# Write the final video clip to the output file
final_clip.write_videofile(output_file, fps=25)
```

But I cant solve this errors (chatgpt and phind cant too):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Q1351\Desktop\Youtuber w piwnicy\Elizabeth\video.py", line 31, in 
video_clip = CompositeVideoClip([image_clip, text_clip.set_start(0.5), voice_clip.set_start(0.5)]).set_audio(music_clip)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Q1351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\CompositeVideoClip.py", line 91, in **init**
audioclips = [v.audio for v in self.clips if v.audio is not None]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Q1351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\CompositeVideoClip.py", line 91, in 
audioclips = [v.audio for v in self.clips if v.audio is not None]
^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'AudioFileClip' object has no attribute 'audio'